# htmleditor: Excel grid losing borders on copy and paste

Tags: extjs

Our users are trying to copy and paste a simple grid from Excel into an ExtJS htmleditor. The Excel grid has true borders around the cells (which are also shown in printout), but if I copy and paste tabular data into the ExtJS htmleditor, the borders are missing.

Is there anything easy I can do (say, enable a config option) to get the borders to show, or will I have to program an extension to htmleditor that allows to select a table and add borders to it with the click of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener that will add a border to the table that's added when you paste an Excel grid into the editor:

View Model

```
{
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    listeners: {
        change: 'onHtmleditorChange'
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
onHtmleditorChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    if(newValue.includes("table border=\"0\"")){
        var replaceVal = newValue.replace("table border=\"0\"", "table border=\"1\"");
        field.setValue(replaceVal);
    }
}
```